# "CSRF Verification Error" API POST request to the buff163

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post

I am making a programme that will automatically make purchases from my account, but have encountered an issue with:

> "CSRF Verification Error"

This happens exclusively with POST requests.
I am making requests using my account cookie, get requests work with no problem.

```
cookies = {
    'Device-Id': '*********',
    'session': '********',
    'remember_me':'********',
    'csrf_token': session.cookies._cookies['buff.163.com']['/']['csrf_token'].value
    }
    response = requests.post('https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/buy', json=payload, headers={'X-Csrftoken': session.cookies._cookies['buff.163.com']['/']['csrf_token'].value}, cookies=cookies)
```

I can't figure out where the error is occurring.

I've tried getting the `csrf_token` get request from the response header and using it immediately - doesn't work.